# How to add a view as a subview of UITableViewCell but on top of all other views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, subview

I have a question - how to add a view as a subview of UITableViewCell but on top of all other views?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

The image should scroll with the cell - save it's position relatively to scroll view (table view in this case).

If the cell is to small in height then the emojis overlay will be cut by the cell on top of current one, so how can I add this emojis overlay as a subview but at the same time display it on top of every cell? I've tried bunch of variants for now and nothing is working for me.

Just adding as a subview of the current window is not working for me because this overlay should scroll with the cell.

Tried code:

```
view.layer.zPosition = 5
cell.contentView.insertSubview(view, aboveSubview: cell.contentView)
cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: view)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: Can u please share the tried code?

Comment: I was trying to increase layer.zPosition for the overlay and decrease it on the table view cells, trying to add as the current window and the last thing I've tried is to insert subview and bring to the front - nothing is working. I guess I know the way on how to do it for UICollectionView, but the project I'm working on is quite large and I think it's not the case to change tableview to collection view for now.
'cell.contentView.insertSubview(view, aboveSubview: parentView)
        cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: view)'

Comment: your question is not clear. you want to add the overlay on each cell of what ?

Comment: basically yep, it will be for every cell, the question is when I add overlay that has height bigger than cell height it get cropped by the cell above of the current cell. So I want to add overlay as a subview of a current cell but it needs to be displayed on top of all views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set cliptobouds = false for your cell.contentview and cell itself.

Otherwise if it is single overlay which you want to be on top of every cell then better implement UISrollViewDelegate and position the overlay accordingly.

Comment: Yep, this working for me - thx a lot.

But I need to have some controls on this kind of view, and now when I add button it is tappable only in the region of parent cell, and when I tap in the area of the button that is placed on the cell that is above of the initial nothing happens. So I can't add some control to overlay like that?

Comment: No, Controls will not work if they lie out of bound of their parents. You better change the design of your cell to mock what you are trying to achieve. For example embed two cells into one for the first cell. Remember you can have multiple kind of cells in a single tableview.